# Как в boost/asio установить сом порту скорость передачи данных?

Tags: c++, com-port, boost.asio

Как в boost/asio установить сом порту скорость передачи данных?

```
boost::asio::serial_port port(context , "portName");
```

чем нужно дополнить, чтоб установить скорость передачи данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где то так (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_base__baud_rate/baud_rate.html)

```
port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
```